# How to implement SwiftUI’s .onDrag modifier with NSImage (macOS)

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nsimage, nsitemprovider

I am building a sandboxed app for `macOS` with `SwiftUI`. I have a `NSImage` that is displayed as `Image(nsImage: myNSImage)`. I want that View to support drag and drop, meaning that it can be dragged to any location that can receive image files.

Here’s my approach:

```
Image(nsImage: myNSImage)
    .onDrag({
        let itemProvider = NSItemProvider()
        itemProvider.suggestedName = "image.png"
        itemProvider.registerDataRepresentation(for: UTType.png) {
            loadHandler in

            loadHandler(nsImage.pngRepresentation, nil)
            print("loadHandler completed") // Never prints !!
            return nil

        }
        return itemProvider
    })
```

This way I can drag the View. But it seems like it isn’t able to provide the image.

The “drop”, i.e. on the Desktop, is simply not working. I would expect that it saves an `"image.png"` in the destination URL, but it doesn’t.

**How can I implement `.onDrag` so that it provides a image file based on `NSImage`?**

*Edit*: I already have tried different `UTType`s, for example `.tiff` in combination with `nsImage.tiffRepresentation` without luck.